# How to display data in particular gridview when particular checkbox is selected?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 6 check boxes in 1 panel, and 6 gridviews i other seven differnt panels.
when i check checkbox 1, the data should be displayed in gridview one and so on.
How to do this?

Comment: Well you have a check changed event subscribe and bind the grid data on that.

Comment: use checkbox_CheckedChanged event to display the gridview data...

Comment: I m not getting CheckedChanged event option when i try to write code. is it available for checkbox list? because i have a list of check box. or should i seperate each check box?

Comment: r u using webapplication or winforms.....

Comment: @abu:For checkboxlist, you have to define the OnSelectedIndexChanged event....I have explained it in my answer.....

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 void firstcheckbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           dridview1.Datasource=something;
           dridview1.Visible=firstcheckbox.Checked;
        }
```

and repeat for other

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the data in  the `gridview` in `OnCheckedChanged` event of CheckBox:
For e.g.:
You have to define event in check box in following way

```
   <asp:CheckBox id="checkbox1" runat="server"
                        AutoPostBack="True"
                        Text="CheckBox1"
                        OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_Clicked"/>.
```

And you have to implement event handler:

```
      void CheckBox1_Clicked(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
      {

         //Here,bind the data in respective gridview

      }
```

Note : For `checkboxlist`, you have to define the  `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event rather than OnCheckedChanged event in following way:

```
 <asp:CheckBoxList id="checkboxlist1" 
           AutoPostBack="True"
           OnSelectedIndexChanged="CheckBox1_Clicked"
           runat="server">
```

For CheckBoxList `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event handler implementation:

```
  void CheckBox1_Clicked(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
  {
     // Iterate through the Items collection of the CheckBoxList 
     // control and bind the data in gridview
     for (int i=0; i<checkboxlist1.Items.Count; i++)
     {

        if (checkboxlist1.Items[i].Selected)
        {

         //Bind the data here in respective gridview

        }

     }

  }
```

Comment: I have checkbox list and inside that 6 list items. then how should i write OnSelectedIndexChanged handler as u mentioned in ur code?

Comment: You can specify the index manually in checkboxlist1.Items[index].Selected by referencing to your listitem.....

Answer (score 0):

In the `Page_Init` event handler, modify the `gridbox.visible` property based on what check boxes are selected.

Answer (score 0):

Please set all checkbox's  `AutoPostBack="True"` And Handle Every checkbox's Click Event.

Comment: There is no Click Event available for checkbox.